# When I use left/right arrow keys, it goes to beginning or end of line

Tags: windows, keyboard

I pressed some shortcut on the keyboard accidentally that now when I edit a text file, if I press left arrow key once, it goes to beginnnig of line, and when I press right arrow key it goes to the end of the line.

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your **alt gr** is stuck.
Try to use another keyboard or the on-screen keyboard to see if the problem occurs.